# Rudin's PMA: Theorem 7.12

Tags: real-analysis

Rudin's statement is as follows.

**Theorem 7.12** If $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $E$, and if $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $E$, then $f$ is continuous on $E$.

This very important result is an immediate corollary of Theorem 7.11.

**Theorem 7.11** Suppose $f_n\to f$ uniformly on a set $E$ in a metric space. Let $x$ be a limit point of $E$, and suppose that
$$\lim_{t\to x}f_n(t)=A_n  (n=1,2,3,...).$$
Then $\{A_n\}$ converges, and
$$\lim_{t\to x}f(t)=\lim_{n\to \infty}A_n.$$
In other words, the conclusion is that
$$\lim_{t\to x}\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(t)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{t\to x}f_n(t).$$

Here is my thought:

If $p$ is a limit point of $E$ and $p\in E$, then I can prove $f$ is continuous at $p$ by **Theorem 4.6 & Theorem 7.11**, the proof is as follows.

**Theorem 4.6** In the situation given in Definition 4.5 (i.e. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces, $E \subset X$, $p\in E$, and $f$ maps $E$ into $Y$.), assume also that $p$ is a limit point of $E$. Then $f$ is continuous at $p$ if and only if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=f(p)$

I know $f_n$ is continuous on $E$, then $f_n$ is continuous at $p$,  according to **Theorem 4.6**, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to p}f_n(x)=f_n(p)(n=1,2,3,...).$

I know $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $E$, then according to **Theorem 7.11** and above process, $\{f_n(p)\}$ converges, and
$$\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(p).$$
In **Definition 7.7** (i.e. The definition of uniform convergence.), rudin pointed that every uniformly convergent sequence is *pointwise convergent* (i.e. ${f_n}$ converges to $f$ pointwise on $E$, which is noticed by **Definition 7.1**.), this means
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(p)=f(p).$$
Then
$$\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=f(p).$$
According to **Theorem 4.6**, $f$ is continuous at $p$.

Here is my question:

Now I think I should prove that with the assumption given by **Theorem 7.12**, $f$ is continuous at which the isolated points in E. Then **Theorem 7.12** is correct. But how to prove this?

By the way, I think many people have other simple ways to prove this theorem, can somebody give me some ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Every function is continuous at isolated points.

Comment: Any sequence converging to an isolated point is eventually constant so continuity at isolated points is obvious.

Comment: @温泽海 Thank you! I didn't aware it at that moment.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I am proving continuity at an isolated point using sequential definition of continuity.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy In baby rudin it may not introduce it, but I find it on the website. I think you are right.